# Impala not able to read full table

Tags: hive, count, apache-spark-sql, impala

I refreshed a table in hive using spark-sql (v 1.6.0), after which impala is not  able to read complete content of the table.

select * from tablename limit 10; is giving some results  where as select count(*) from tablename is giving the following error

> Error seeking to 1073561824 in file: hdfs://server/products/path/db/tablename/part-00017 Error(255): Unknown error 255

Same error occurs if I execute query with **where** clause as well, and all these queries are working fine when accessed through Hive.

Comment: Did you refresh the Impala metadata cache?

Comment: Yes I did, i refreshed.

Comment: Did you find more details in the `impalad` logs server-side? Do you run the Impala Catalog to make sure that all the `impalad` daemons have their cache in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running

```
invalidate metadata yourtable.
```

maybe this can clarify the difference when use [refresh](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_refresh.html) or [invalidate metadata](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html)

Comment: I have tableau connected to these tables using impala, so how do I execute this command.

Comment: No idea how tableau works, try posting a new answer. If you connect to impala directly using the client or hue (in cdh distro) you should be able to run this command with problem. Even more, this is just a sql statement in impala, you should be able to run it as any other query.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you don't read and write the file at the same time
Ex: Read parquet file f1, join with some others and then write it into f1 -> failed